# ¿Cómo solucionó este error en java web?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Cuando hago un método para *obtener el último registro de la base de datos +1*  he intento correr el programa me da un error que es el siguiente:

> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation
>   processor
>   'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor'
>   less than -source '1.8' Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
>   Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with
>   generation. Note: Optional file was not found:
>   META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation. Note:
>   Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with
>   generation. Note: Optional file was not found:
>   META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation. Note: Some
>   input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> 1 warning

Este es el método que he creado

```
public int nextCodigo(){
    String select="SELECT MAX(in_idProveedor) FROM f_t_proveedor";
    Query consulta = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(select);
    Integer resultado = (Integer) consulta.getSingleResult();
    return resultado+1;
}
```

Comment: Veo que es un warning, no es un error. Fuera de eso, estás escribiendo un query de JPQL, que no es lo mismo que un query nativo. Si lo que quieres es ejecutar un query nativo, sería mejor usar `getEntityManager().createNativeQuery()` a menos que el nombre de tu clase mapeada sea `f_t_proveedor`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si justamente eso era. ;)